# Send notifications to inactive users using Azure Mobile Services. Where to save the "lastLoginDate" and filter on it?

Tags: c#, ios, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have always been using Parse to manage my backend but switched to Azure due to the better integration with ASP.NET and Xamarin. In Parse I created a PFInstallation object and associated whatever property I needed to filter on before sending push notifications.

In Azure Mobile Services I am using the following code (in Xamarin iOS) to register the device:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        try {
            var languageCode = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages [0];
            ServiceClient.GetPush ().RegisterNativeAsync (deviceToken, new []{ languageCode }).ContinueWith ((t) => {
                Console.WriteLine ("Device registration successful!");
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Could not register device for push notifications: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I would like to have a way to remind my inactive users that they should play again. In Parse I just associated a "lastLoginDate" attribute to the PFInstallation object. How can I achieve the same with Azure Mobile Services?
As of now I am only able to filter based on the user's device language (because I save it as a tag) but not on the "lastLoginDate".

PS: in my backend I would like to have a code like this

```
var users = registrations.Where(u => u.LastLoginDate <= testDate);
SendNotificationToUsers(users);
```

**UPDATE**

I read on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx) that you can use Tag Expressions to filter registrations but in the article it's not specified if you can use boolean expressions involving a date comparison. Any help on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to have the device register with a tag with the current date each time the user opens the app. So today I use the app, I register my token for the tag "last-use-2015-03-02". Tomorrow if I use the app again I will reregister with the tag "last-use-2015-03-03", replacing the device registration for 2015-03-02.

Then each day have a scheduler that sends a message to the tag for a week ago (for example). So a week from now on March 9, I can send a notification to all devices with the tag "last-use-2015-03-02" reminding them to come back.

Comment: I had written in my question (and then erased it, look at the edits) that I wanted to avoid this method because it's not very manageable although I think it's the only way left. I still hope someone has a better solutions than this

Comment: The alternative is to store each device's last used date in your own database table and query that table when sending pushes. To me this is less manageable and duplicates what the hub is already doing. Can you elaborate on what seems unmanageable? To answer your other question, each tag is just a string and each device has it or doesn't. There is no tag substring matching or other comparison.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about creating a table to hold a tuples of registrationId and LastLoginDate but yeah, it does duplicate the data. Sorry I just wanted to point that it's less beautiful than Parse's solution but it does the work so thank you.